# why should a producer write to odd number of servers in case of a distributed message queue

Tags: replication, message-queue, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-system

In a recent interview, i was asked to design a distributed message queue. I modeled it as a multi-partitioned system where each partition has a replica set with one primary and one or more secondaries for high availability. The writes from the producer are processed by the primary and are replicated synchronously, which means a message is not committed unless a quorum of the replica set has applied it. He then identified the potential availability problem when the primary of a replica set dies (which means a producer writing to that partition won't be able to write until a new primary is elected for the replica set) and asked me about the solution where the producer writes to the same message to multiple servers (favoring availability instead of consistency). He then asked me what would be the difference if the client wrote to 2 servers vs 3 servers, a question i failed to answer. In general, i thought it was more of an Even vs Odd question and I guessed it had something to do with quorums (i.e. majority) but failed to see how it would impact a consumer reading data. Needless to say, this question cost me the job and still continues to puzzle me to this day. I would appreciate any solutions and/or insights and/or suggestions for one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I understood from your question about the new system:

You won't have a primary replica anymore so you don't need to elect one and instead will work simply on a quorum based system to have a higher availability? - if that is correct than maybe this will give you some closure :) - otherwise feel free to correct me.

Assuming you read and write from / to multiple random nodes and those nodes don't replicate the data on their own, the solution lies in the principle of quorums. In simple cases that means that you need to write and read always at least to/from `n/2 + 1` nodes. So if you would write to 3 nodes you could have up to 5 servers, while if you'd write to 2 nodes you could only have up to 3 servers.

The slightly more complicated quorum is based on the rules:

- `R + W > N`
- `W > N / 2`
- (R - read quorum, W - write quorum, N - number of nodes)

This would give you some more variations for

- from how many servers you need to read
- how many servers you can have in general

From my understanding for the question, that is what I would have used to formulate an answer and I don't think that the difference between 2 and 3 has anything to do with even or odd numbers. Do you think this is the answer your interviewer was looking for or did I miss something?

**Update:**

To clarify as the thoughts in the comment are, which value would be accepted.

In the quorum as I've described it, you would accept the latest value. The can be determined with a simple logical clock. The quorums guarantee that you will retrieve at least one item with the latest information. And in case of a network partitioning or failure when you can't read the quorum, you will know that it's impossible guarantee retrieving the latest value.

On the other hand you suggested to read all items and accept the most common one. I'm not sure, this alone will guarantee to have always the latest item.

Comment: I did some reading today and i believe what he was looking for was a dynamo-style replication, where the producer writes the message to 'N' servers. Now, if the consumer contacts all the servers and accepts the value that is most common, then an even number of servers would be a problem. if N is even (say 2), a network partition of one of the servers would make it impossible for the consumer to select the correct value. I guess this might have been his implication where having odd number of servers would help.